# I can run my C codes on a workspace , but i can not run them as a single files

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm having a little problem, wish to find some help here,
my problems appear when i try to run a single .c file , it shows me the error :

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o :
>   Dans la fonction « _start » : (.text+0x20) : référence indéfinie vers « main »
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.13 seconds

i can run my codes if i put them inside a workspace and then build the task (CTRL + SHIFT + B) , but i need code some single files , so why I can't run them as a single file ? 
I really need to find the solution .
Help please , Thanks .

the error screenshot :
[click here to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaFjV.png)

Comment: If your individual files do not have a main () function, you will not be able to compile them individually, if you can enclose your code in a main () function, even if you then have to delete it

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you don't have a main?

Comment: Your picture does not show a failure of running, it shows a failure of building; linking to be precise. Are you aware of the differences between those three things? Understanding them is needed for seeing the problem of compiling a file without a main(), then try to link it and plan to run it afterwards...

Comment: actually i have a main fonction , im sure the problem is not in the code , the problem must be  in the settings or maybe the compiler ?

Comment: Mr. Yunnosch , yep i konw that there is no way to copile a programme if he dont have the main () function , 
i cant rvrn run a hello world programme , so can you help me to solve this building problem ?

Comment: _Nb_, you are compiling a different file then the one you have open in the editor in the screenshot. See [this short tutorial](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html).